# Handling an AJAX response as a document?

Tags: javascript, ajax, hashbang

I'm trying to implement AJAX with shebang - meaning that `example.com/#!/somepage.php` is simply `example.com/somepage.php` loaded into the content area of an AJAX site.

The obvious way of doing this is to just request `somepage.php` and then replace the entire contents of the `documentElement` with the new document. However that seems to kind of defeat the purpose of AJAX.

Instead, I'm thinking of trying to load `somepage.php`, and then extracting the `content` part of the page and simply put that in the content area.

To do this, I *could* use a regex to look for `/<div id="content">.*</div>/` but that would be a very bad idea (the simplest problem being "which `</div>` ends the content?). Instead, I'd like to be able to just do something like `ajaxresponse.getElementById('content')`, but how would I go about converting `ajaxresponse` to a `document` (or `documentFragment`) object?

Or is this just the wrong approach to implementing such an AJAX setup? Would I be better off having the server side check for `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` and only send back the content area?

Comment: Is including `jQuery` to do that out of question? With jQuery Ajax's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/): `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`. I know you should know that better than me, is there any issue with `shebang` and jQuery?

Comment: Couldn't your `#!` handler simply make a different request than the page verbatim?  For example, when `#!` handles `/somepage.php`, request `/somepage.php?json` (which returns something convenient to use).

Comment: With pure JS you could also append your requested page to a hidden element (or just create it on the fly), then grab your loaded content div through `getElementById` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requesting the `#!`'d page verbatim, request a variant that is compatible with your `#!` handler.

This approach takes two steps.

1. Expose your content pages via JSON.  Make this service available to requests that satisfy a particular condition, such as a special get parameter, extension, a header, etc.  For example, `/somepage.php?json` might serve the content of `/somepage.php` in JSON.
2. Write your `#!` handler so that when it handles a request, it calls upon the service you defined above for that page.  For example, when `example.com/#!/somepage.php` is loaded and you handle `somepage.php`, request `somepage.php?json` instead, and propagate the content of that request as appropriate.

This approach affords you a number of benefits.

- Reduced response size of the AJAX request
- Reduced server-side load, since no HTML need be rendered
- Avoids HTML parsing and some expensive DOM manipulation
- No dependence on browser to send appropriate AJAX-related headers

Comment: (I posted this as a comment, but thought I might as well promote it to an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't actually need to use a regular expression to get the content from the returned data. With jQuery, for example, it's simply a matter of using the `context` argument of the $ selector ([live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raffaele181188/fBfas/#base))

```
$.get("/", {}, function(data){
    $("#text").append($("#login", data));
});​
```

Also note that shebang navigation is often associated with some Javascript framework